# In Android Studio, how do you configure gradle to automatically replace AdMob's AdUnitId when creating signed release APKs

Tags: android, gradle, admob

Standard guidance shows that this should be placed where the AdMob banner should be displayed in you MainActivity.xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/default_background"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

In my strings.xml I have defined the following:

```
<string name = "banner_ad_unit_id" >
    ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
    </string>
```

How do I get this value automatically replaced with my personal AdMob ID when creating a release build/signed apk file?

Comment: you can use different flavors including different strings.xml files http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Gradle_Build_Variants_Example

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the value contained in your strings.xml?

Comment: I want default builds/debug to have the sample ad to comply with the AdMob terms of service. Then, when creating a version of the app to publish, I would like to automatically replace it with the personal string.

Comment: Please add as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @A.S. , Your answer describes how to do this with various productFlavors, which I already have implemented. I am interested in how to do this with various buildTypes.

Answer (score 11):

This is my solution for this problem, and I know it is not flawless, but it works quite well.

In app `build.gradle` you can define string resources upon `buildTypes` ('...' are other definitions not related):

**build.gradle** (app)**:**

```
android{
   ...
   buildTypes{

      debug {  //Debug build type
         ...
         //In here only TestAd keys (theese are public test keys free to use)
         resValue("string","mobileads_app_id","ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713")
         resValue("string","banner_ad_unit_id_no_1","ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111")
         resValue("string","banner_ad_unit_id_no_2","ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111")
         resValue("string","interstitial_ad_unit_no_1","ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712")
         ...
      }

      release {  //Release build type
         ...
         //In here only your own production Ad keys
         resValue("string","mobileads_app_id","/*YOUR REAL MOBILEADS KEY*/")
         resValue("string","banner_ad_unit_id_no_1","/*YOUR REAL AD UNIT ID KEY*/")
         resValue("string","banner_ad_unit_id_no_2","/*YOUR REAL AD UNIT ID KEY*/")
         resValue("string","interstitial_ad_unit_no_1","/*YOUR REAL INTERSTITIAL AD KEY*/")
         ...
      }              
   } 
}
```

In your `strings.xml` you should comment that your Ad keys are defined in app `build.gradle` or you may loose track if you don't remember it...

**strings.xml:**

```
<resources>
...
    <!--Note !! AdView keys are defined in app.gradle for debug and release buildTypes -->
...
</resources>
```

You can now reference to the string definitions you have entered in the app `build.gradle` file as they were written in the `strings.xml`, and the correct value is selected upon **debug** release when debugging code, and **release** release when releasing code for the app store:

**fragment_layout.xml:**

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id_no_1"  
            android:id="@+id/fragment_no_1_adView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
class MainActivity :AppCompatActivity(), FragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener, ...
{
   ...
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
   {
      ...
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      //You can refer to the AdView code in string definition in a common way
      MobileAds.initialize(this,getString(R.string.mobileads_app_id))

      ... 

      interstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
      interstitialAd.adUnitId = getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_no_1)

      ...

   }
}
```

**fragment.kt:**

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): 
    View? {

    adRequest = AdRequest
        .Builder()
        .build()

    stationListAdView.loadAd(adRequest)

    (activity as MainActivity).stationListToPriceInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
```

RG

Comment: Note!! In AS4.1 and AS4.2 (prior to AS4.2C8 (not yet released in writing)) there is a false negative Lint/IDE message when referencing theese value. Please read about the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/158846277